# ¿Qué significa "ñapa" en el titulo de la canción "ñapa es" de Ska-p?

Tags: españa, coloquialismos, letras-de-canciones

La cancion *ñapa es* es una canción muy famosa del grupo Ska-p.

Se puede ver el video aquí: [ñapa es](https://youtu.be/1-AMGtQDhzE)

Mi pregunta: ¿qué significa la palabra *ñapa*?

En el web, el título está muchas veces traducido por "Spain is (like that)" y la canción critica la política en España y su estribillo termina en "España es así". Pues, mi conjetura es que *ñapa* es una forma de slang para España. Como eso: España  -> Paña -> ñapa (conjetura).

¿Tiene sentido?

Comment: Es-pa-ña, invirtiendo el orden de las sílabas: ña-pa-es. Es un juego común

Comment: La palabra Ñapa en Ciudad del Carmen, en el estado de Campeche, México, significa: extra, pilón, propina; casi en desuso por las nuevas corrientes globales de palabras modernas usadas por las nuevas generaciones.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

En España, y sobre todo en la región de Castilla-La Mancha (donde pude vivir durante algunos años), una *napa* es un apaño, generalmente hecho deprisa y de mala manera.

En mi caso lo he visto usar mucho en programación, cuando había que arreglar alguna incidencia en el código y no había tiempo de hacer algo en condiciones, se hacía una *ñapa* para salir del paso, un arreglo rápido.

En el caso de la canción, yo diría que simplemente usa el juego de palabras entre *España* y *ñapa* por su similitud sonora, pero no es que la segunda venga de la primera. Simplemente quiere decir que España, y sobre todo su política, es un país de ñapas.

Comment: Parece bueno. Ellos estan de Vallecas en Madrid, no lejos de Castilla-La Mancha.

Comment: Yo creo que la palabra _ñapa_ está bastante extendida, al menos por el norte también se usa, básicamente es un sinónimo de [chapuza](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8baa46k). Cierto que en programación también se utiliza bastante.

Comment: Sí. En catalán existe también _nyap_ con idéntico significado.

Comment: @blonfu aquí en Andalucía la gente la entiende (igual por contexto) pero no se usa apenas. En Castilla-La Mancha sí se usaba bastante cuando vivía allí, por eso lo comenté en la respuesta. No sé exactamente cuál será su ámbito de uso, puede que hacia el norte sí se haya extendido más.

Comment: Es posible, no sabía que en el sur no se usaba. Dices que la gente lo entiende, me pregunto si tendrá algo que ver la serie _Manos a la obra_ , uno de los personajes usaba mucho esa palabra y fue una serie bastante vista en su época.

Answer (score 4):

Si divides "**Ñapa Es**" en tres silabas: "ña" "pa" "es" y las lees en orden inverso, tienes "**España**".
No creo que tenga más misterio, aunque [Wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/%C3%B1apa) define "ñapa" como

> f. amer. Añadidura,propina.

Comment: Esto recuerda mucho a las palabras reordenadas del https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunfardo .

Answer (score 0):

Para mí, en España el significado de ñapa es chapuza.
Parece que el origen de la palabra es quechua. Si en hispanoamérica significa añadido o propina, tiene sentido lo que aquí entendemos por ñapa: añadido (provisional), chapuza, apaño, improvisación (a la que en España somos muy dados, somos maestros de la improvisación, lo cual en algunas situaciones difíciles es una virtud, y en otras hace que seamos un poco desastrosos)

Comment: ¡Hola! Tu respuesta es similar a otras respuestas anteriores. Si estás de acuerdo con lo que dicen y quieres mostrar tu apoyo, lo mejor es votar esas respuestas y/o dejar un comentario, para evitar tener muchas respuestas iguales. Si lo que quieres es ampliar o mejorar la información o dar otro enfoque, considera [edit]ar tu respuesta para añadir una explicación, decir de qué forma se usa en tu zona, aportar elementos históricos, etc. Más info en [answer].